# How do I find what common notations stand for?

Tags: real-analysis, notation

I am reading a paper that defines a Gelfand triples. The paper states:

> "We define the Gelfand triple of Hilbert spaces $V \subset H \subset V^*$ by
>
> $$H= (L^2(D), <\cdot, \cdot>, ||\cdot||), \quad V= (H_0^1 (D), <\nabla\cdot, \nabla\cdot>, ||\cdot||_V = || \nabla\cdot ||)$$
>
> where $D \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ denotes a bounded open set, with Lipschitz boundary $\partial D$, and $v^*$ is the dual of $V$ with respect to the pairing induced by $H$."

What is $L^2(D)$ and what is $H_0^1(D)$? How would I search for this (on google or here)?

I would guess $L^2(D)$ is functions that are $L^2$ integrable on D, i.e. $\int_D |f|^2 d\mu < \infty$ (though I'm not sure what the measure $\mu$ is in this context). What about $H_0^1$?

Comment: Say you didn't know anything about the formula being described in the paper, the best advice I can give you would be to try searching using the raw $\LaTeX$ symbols on Google. So for instance, `H^1_0` returned results for `Sobolev spaces`, which should allow you to refine your search even further. If you want to search on a particular site using Google, remember to use `site:example.com [search term]`.

Another way of solving this problem is to search for other definitions of the same concept online. Instead of searching for the symbols, try looking up `Gelfand triple of Hilbert spaces`.

Comment: To the good advice of EdOverflow, let me add that, if you find a sketchy definition like the one you wrote, it is probably just a reminder of some concept that the author considers as "well-known". So if you don't know anything about it, it may be a good idea to temporarily close the article you are reading and gather some more information somewhere else. (The hard part is to do this without falling [in the rabbit hole](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/617625/8157)).