# Probability and Measure Theory: the gifted Mind

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

It seems I've got to the point where I no longer see the immediate applications of theorems. 
I study actuarial science and am attempting to describe probability and measure theory more intuitively but then I come across theorems like Radon-Nikodym whose immediate applications escape me.

Is this a usual thing for the average mathematics student? Does practicing make me a math fraud who just learns to identify rather than reason. I feel incomplete if I can't apply it to a completely new and foreign situation without needing exercises.

How do gifted students, and obviously I'm not the caliber of Terrence Tao, but what makes his understanding different?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11267/what-are-some-interpretations-of-von-neumanns-quote).

Comment: How do mathematicians reason without examples is what I'm getting at. Collaboration and pace?

Comment: Possibly helpful is the google search ["Radon-Nikodym theorem" + application + probability](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Radon-Nikodym+theorem%22+application+probability), although I would imagine you've already tried something like this.

Comment: *How do mathematicians reason without examples* --- Often you'll find (at least I've found this to be the case) that textbook treatments of a topic are many-times-removed streamlined/sanitized versions of the original development of a topic, for efficient learning purposes. For example, see my answer to [Where was it first proved that the cardinality of the continuum equals the cardinality of the power set of the naturals?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/6299/264) for an indication of how our concept of the power set of a set arose rather late in the development of set theory.