# How do I work with identifications in differential geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces

I have some uncertainty when it comes to manipulating differentials and the frequent use of identifications. I understand we make a lot of identifications between spaces when doing computations, but I still feel uneasy about some of their justification even in simple settings. For example, following a paragraph in LeeRM, suppose $\mathbb{R}^n$ has the Euclidean metric $\bar g$ and $V$ is an $n$-dimensional real inner product space endowed with metric $g_p(v,w) = \langle v, w\rangle$ at every $p\in V$. I understand there is a canonical isomorphism between $T_pV$ and $V$ suppressed in this notation in order to make sense of the right-hand side since $v,w\in T_pV$ while the inner product is defined on $V$.

Let $(b_1,\dots,b_n)$ be an orthonormal basis for $V$, I want to show that the map $F \colon\mathbb{R}^n \to V$ defined by $x\mapsto x^ib_i$ is an isometry. I can see that it is a diffeomorphism (in coordinates it is the identity), so I check the pullback condition. Letting $x^1,\dots, x^n$ be global coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $y^1,\dots, y^n$ be the global coordinates on $V$ that pick out the components of our orthonormal basis, I can think in coordinates and write $v,w\in T_{x^ib_i}\mathbb{R}^n$ as $v = v^j\partial_j|_{x^ib_i}, w = w^k\partial_k|_{x^ib_i}$.
$$(F^*g)_x(v,w) = g_{x^ib_i}(dF_x(v),dF_x(w)) = \langle dF_x(v),dF_x(w)\rangle = 
v^jw^k\langle \partial y_j|_{x^ib_i},\partial y_k|_{x^ib_i}\rangle$$
Here I used the fact that the Jacobian of the coordinate representation of $F$ is the identity.
Now to make sense of the expression on the right-hand side, I have to recall the canonical identification between vector spaces and their tangent spaces defined by LeeSM, where we identify $v$ with a particular derivation $D_v|_a$ which takes directional derivatives. Unraveling the definition of $\partial y_j|_{x^ib_i}$ we can actually see that it equals $D_{b^j}|_{x^ib_i}$. Hence
$$v^jw^k\langle \partial y_j|_{x^ib_i},\partial y_k|_{x^ib_i}\rangle = v^jw^k\langle b^j,b^k\rangle = v^jw^k\delta^j_k = \sum_i v^iw^i$$
Then undoing the isomorphism between $v,w\in T_{x^ib_i}\mathbb{R}^n$ and their coefficients in the canonical basis $v = v^j\partial_j|_{x^ib_i}, w = w^k\partial_k|_{x^ib_i}$, this is just $v\cdot w = g_x(v,w)$ in the sense of the Euclidean metric.

But this is certainly not how any person who values their time would think of these things. Instead I would observe that if $v,w\in T_x\mathbb{R}^n \cong \mathbb{R}^n$ then I might think
something like
$$(F^*g)_x(v,w) = g_{x^ib_i}(dF_x(v),dF_x(w)) = \langle dF_x(v),dF_x(w)\rangle = 
\langle v^jb_j,w^kb_k\rangle = \sum_i v^iw^i = v \cdot w = g_x(v,w)$$
Here I reasoned that $F(x) = Bx$ so $dF_x = B$ and so $dF_x(v) = v^ib_i$ etc., where I am basically always viewing $v,w$ as just lists of numbers throughout, and I am a bit more fast and loose with the differential because of my familiarity with calculus in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is there a happy medium between these two approaches, or is this just something you get used to? Any thoughts/insights on these ideas is appreciated.

Comment: You'll get used to it eventually.

Comment: This is the type of thing you do say once or twice in excruciating detail (maybe 4 times in my case) and then you'll never forget it and you'll know for sure how to fill in the gory details. Eventually, you just get the hang of the commonly recurring theme in mathematics: "transport of structure", and you'll be able to do these gymnastics mentally.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11267/what-are-some-interpretations-of-von-neumanns-quote#:~:text=John%20Von%20Neumann%20once%20said,about%20the%20method%20of%20characteristics.

Comment: "Differential geometry is the study of things, which are invariant under change of notation." While this a joke quote, it is true. It is painful in the beginning, but no big deal later.